# iptables and OpenVPN configuration

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have following `iptables` rules:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

I have an issue with them. If there is a `-m state --state NEW` - then I can't connect to the OpenVPN. If I change the first rule of those to:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

I can connect and use OpenVPN freely.

Why does `-m state --state NEW` works likes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state extension differentiates the following states for a connection: `NEW`, `ESTABLISHED`, `RELATED`, `INVALID`, plus three others which are rarely used.  A packet is only `NEW` if, informally speaking, server and client haven't been communicating in any way.  After that, a packet usually belongs to an `ESTABLISHED` connection or is `RELATED` to one.

This means that you'll need to accept packets with state `ESTABLISHED` and `RELATED`.  Currently, only the first packet is accepted and later ones are silently dropped.  Use the following to fix your setup:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```